# Sitecore - Adding route in Application_Start

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I am using sitecore 7.5 and I need to add new route in application_start in order to use it in ajax call but when I run the application it seems that sitecore deals with the route as content item any help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code that creates a route for you. In global.asax.cs you will call RegisterRoutes **from App_Start event handler**:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

And there you specify your route as:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "test",
             url: "mvc/Forms/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Forms", action = "Test", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
    }
```

You will have /mvc/ prefix in this case that will handle your route to specifies controller, so you will call it as:

```
/mvc/Forms/Test/{you_may_pass_some_optional_GUID_here}
```

This will route to FormsController class action method Test(string id) but you may omit id parameter

**A bit of attention:** Please note that setting route in Application_Start **is not** the best way of doing that; much better is to implement mapping routes at Initialize pipeline, as it fits Sitecore architecture:

```
public class Initialize
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        MapRoutes();
    }

    private void MapRoutes()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
                "Forms.Test", 
                "forms/test", 
                new
                {
                    controller = "FormsController",
                    action = "Test"
                },
                new[] { "Forms.Controller.Namespace" });
     }
}
```

**The rest of implementation:** Also I have previously wrote an article in my blog about how to implement ajax call to a route, that will guide you through the rest of the implementation process:

http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/editing-content-on-a-cd-server

**Update:** Please also make sure your config has a handler to handle your prefix, see below:

```
<customHandlers>
    <handler trigger="~/mvc/" handler="sitecore_mvc.ashx" />
```

Comment: I really appreciate your quick response but my problem is not solved ,the url still redirecting to something like this http://xxx/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx?item=%2fapi%2faccount%2fregister&user=extranet%5cAnonymous&site=website

Comment: Mostafa, I have updated my answer (at the bottom) in order to help you sort out what you mentioned in the comment above